# LINQ search filter logic

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have apartment entity and I want to get apartments based on my filters.

this is my search entity

```
public class Search
{
    public bool isStudio {get;set;}

    public bool isNoPlanning {get;set;}

    public bool isMultiRoom {get;set;}

    public int[] NumberOfRooms {get;set;}
}
```

this is my current search logic.

```
var apartments = buildRepost.Get(buildId).Where(condStates => 
   (searchModel.NumberOfRooms != null 
     && searchModel.NumberOfRooms.Contains(condStates.RoomsCount.ToString()) 
   || ((searchModel.IsStudio && condStates.IsStudio)) 
   || ((searchModel.IsNoPlanning && condStates.IsFreePlaning)) 
   || ((searchModel.IsMultiRoom && condStates.RoomsCount >= 4)));
```

The problem with this logic is that I got the wrong result when all fields are false and `null`. For example when `isStudio`, `IsNoplaning` and `isMultiRoom` are false and `numberofRooms` is `null` I should have got all apartments but instead, I got an empty array. Any help?

Comment: can you explain what you want to extract actually?

Comment: You can try to evaluate it manually - put false instead of searchModel.<something> - then the filter looks like (false && ...) || (false && ...) || ... which is always false.

Comment: Where are you getting `searchModel` inside your `linq` query?

Comment: This code can't compile because an `int[].Contains` can't accept a string and there are case differences. Please post correct code because all details matter in code.

Answer (score 2):

the `searchModel.NumberOfRooms != null` checker in the where clause causes the problem, you are not mathcing it with any of the `condStates` properties and the `searchModel.Is.....` properties

Make your `searchModel` as a checker in an `if` statement then build the query from the `if searchModel` conditions.

```
var query = buildRepost.Get(buildId).AsQueryable();

if (searchModel.NumberOfRooms != null)
{
    query = query.Where(condStates  => searchModel.NumberOfRooms.Contains(condStates.RoomsCount.ToString());
}
if (searchModel.IsStudio)
{
    query = query.Where(condStates  => condStates.IsStudio); 
}
if (searchModel.IsNoPlaning)
{
    query = query.Where(condStates  => condStates.IsFreePlaning)
}
if (searchModel.IsMultiRoom)
{
    query = query.Where(condStates  => condStates.RoomsCount >= 4)
}

var results = query.ToList()
```

Comment: you left a condition RoomsCount i think :  query = query.Where(condStates  => condStates.IsMultiRoom && condStates..RoomsCount >= 4)

Comment: This is a better solution

Comment: Yup, chaining `Where` clauses is the way to go. Much more readable and robust.

Answer (score 0):

```
(searchModel.NumberOfRooms != null 
     && searchModel.NumberOfRooms.Contains(condStates.RoomsCount.ToString())
```

This is always going to be false when the `NumberOfRooms` is `null` (due to the null check), and given that the other bool values are all false, you will get no results.

Instead if you change to:

```
(searchModel.NumberOfRooms == null 
     || searchModel.NumberOfRooms.Contains(condStates.RoomsCount.ToString())
```

You will either get everything (when the `NumberOfRooms` is null, or just the records that match the `RoomsCount` (when the `NumberOfRooms` is not null).

Note that in this case, if `NumberOfRooms` is null you will still return everything regardless of your bool filters. Which seems to be what your code requires, but I'm not sure is what you actually require, so you might want to check that.

Comment: In this case i will get wrong result when only one parameter would be true.